# How to configure Visual Studio to use Perforce Merge (P4Merge)?

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn, perforce, p4v

Can I use Perforce merge with Visual Studio and Tortoise SVN?

How can I configure them?

The reason for asking and answering it is that personally I'm a big fan of Perforce, however at the moment I'm working in an SVN environment. This is to document how to configure them for my own and everyone else's benefit.

Answer (score 3):

To configure **Visual Studio**

- Go to Visual Studio / Options / Source Control / Subversion User
  tools, and set it like this
- External diff tool C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe -dw $(Base)
  $(Mine)
- External merge tool
  C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe -dw -nb $(BaseName) -nl $(MineName) -nr $(TheirName) -nm $(MergedName) $(Base) $(Mine) $(Theirs) $(Merged)

[image]

To configure **TortoiseSVN**:

- Start / All Programs / TortoiseSVN / Settings
- Set Diff viewer to C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe -dw %base %mine
- Set Merge Tool to C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe -dw -nb
  %bname -nl %yname -nr %tname -nm Merged %base %mine %theirs
  %merged

Comment: You migth want to enclose those identifiers in double quotes to accomodate for white space in file names.